# check the existence of value on other Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, np

I have two data frames F1 and F2 containing both the column id1, id2.

F1 contains two columns `F1[id1,id2]`.
F2 contains three column [id1,id2,Description]
I wante to test if `F2['id1']`exists in `F1['id1']` OR F2['id2']`exists in`F1['id2'] then i must addd a colmun in F1 with Description of this id1 or id2 in F2` .
The contens of F1 and F2 are [are HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z35e.png). The Output That im attending on F1 is  [also HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHgt0.png)
I created F1 and F2 like This

```
     F1 = {'id1': ['x22', 'x13','NaN','x421'],'id2':['NaN','223','788','NaN']}
     F1 = pd.DataFrame(data=F1)
     F2 = {'id1': ['x22', 'NaN','NaN','x413','x421'],'id2':['NaN','223','788','NaN','233'],'Description':['California','LA','NY','Havnover','Munich']}
     F2 = pd.DataFrame(data=F2)
```

Actually i tried several solutions . But nothing helps me to do it . 
Help please

Comment: Do you need `df = F1.merge(F2,  how='left')` ? Or `df = F1.merge(F2,  how='left', on=['id1','id2'])` ?

Comment: i want from the two dataframe F1 and F2. Add a column in F1 Filled Like shown in the picture shown in the post.

Comment: @jezrael it is not my case!!

Comment: Can you create `F3` with expected output?

Comment: The output is in the File F1   `F3 = {'id1': ['x22', 'x13','NaN','x421'],'id2':['NaN','223','788','NaN'],'Description': ['California','LA','NY','Munich']}
F3 = pd.DataFrame(data=F3)`

Comment: the output will be in the File F1 . With adding a new column of description

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the solution is in F1 . F1 have only 4 lines . To explain more first we begin with the first line in F1 . If it has id1 not null or id2 notnull, x22 exist in F1 so we have to put in the first line of the added line california. In second line we do the samething with searching 223 in F1 and we find it so 2nd will takes LA . Next we will search for 788 that exists so we print 'NY' in the related line. The last line corresponds to id2=421 we search it and we write Munich in the last line ..

Comment: Lets Know that F1 can have more then 4 lines .. In this case the value will be Null cause don"t have an id in F2. Hope that i clear

Comment: I got solution, working on answer.

Comment: do you see what i mean.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#if necessary replace string NaN to missing values
F1 = F1.replace('NaN', np.nan)
F2 = F2.replace('NaN', np.nan)
```

For each column remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), missing valeus by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and create index by `id` column by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
s1 = F2.drop_duplicates('id1').dropna(subset=['id1']).set_index('id1')['Description']
s2 = F2.drop_duplicates('id2').dropna(subset=['id2']).set_index('id2')['Description']
```

Then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by columns from `F1` with [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
F1['Description'] = F1['id1'].map(s1).combine_first(F1['id2'].map(s2))
print (F1)
    id1  id2 Description
0   x22  NaN  California
1   x13  223          LA
2   NaN  788          NY
3  x421  NaN      Munich
```